# Import Multiple XML files into SoapUI

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, soapui

Started a new job couple of months ago, and requires basic day-to-day use of SoapUI for executing batches of tests that require some visual verification (we haven't automated the visual part yet).

However, I now have a whole bunch of new xmls file I need to import into a project, and I was wondering whether somebody had a groovy script or something, to import the files, and use the content within the file as the xml text to pass,. via HTTP requests.

Basically, I want what [albciff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218618/albciff) has done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161008/how-to-import-existing-soap-request-messages-to-soapui). But turn my xml files into HTTP steps.

I have tried modifying his script to include the correct classes for HTTP, but I am getting an exception which I cant fix

UPDATE 28/01

I am just using the free/standard edition of SoapUI. I have limited codding/scripting knowledge as I'm just a functional tester :(

My current groovy script is

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.HttpRequestStepFactory
import groovy.io.FileType

// get the current testCase to add testSteps later
def tc = testRunner.testCase
// get the testStep as template to create the other requests
def tsTemplate = tc.getTestStepByName("Template")
// create the factory to create testSteps
def testStepFactory = new HttpRequestStepFactory()

def requestDir = new File("C://directory//..//final_dir")
// for each xml file in the directory
requestDir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
  def newTestStepName = file.getName()
  // create the config
  def testStepConfig = testStepFactory.createConfig( tsTemplate.getOperation(), newTestStepName )
  // add the new testStep to current testCase
  def newTestStep = tc.insertTestStep( testStepConfig, -1 )
  // set the request which just create with the file content
  newTestStep.getTestRequest().setRequestContent(file.getText())
}
```

And the exception I get when running is

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.HttpTestRequestStep.getOperation()
>   is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions:
>   getAssertions() error at line: 14

Comment: Do you have SoapUI-Pro, or the free version? Can you show what have you done so far? Have a read through [ask].

Comment: Can you share your code, and the exception? this way we could provide more help to your question `:)`.

Comment: I posted some more information, any help you can give is greatly appreciated. Will just save me the time of having to manually copy and paste the text from 758 xml files into 758 steps. I can clone, but the content in each file is different, so still have to manually copy the content. Also if it makes a difference, the steps are Method = POST.

Comment: @AlexCooke I add a possible solution, I tried an it works. With your sample code it was easier to help you `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there `:)`, try this way (use `HttpRequestStepFactory.createNewTestStep` instead of `HttpRequestStepFactory.createConfig`):

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.WsdlTestRequestStepFactory
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.registry.HttpRequestStepFactory
import groovy.io.FileType

// get the current testCase to add testSteps later
def tc = testRunner.testCase
// get the testStep as template to create the other requests
def tsTemplate = tc.getTestStepByName("Template")
// create the factory to create testSteps
def testStepFactory = new HttpRequestStepFactory()
def requestDir = new File("C://directory//..//final_dir")
// for each xml file in the directory
requestDir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES){ file ->
  def newTestStepName = file.getName()
  // get the template endpoint
  def endpoint = tsTemplate.getPropertyValue('Endpoint')
  // create the config using endpoint and your method (post in your case)
  def testStepConfig  = testStepFactory.createNewTestStep(tc,newTestStepName,endpoint,'POST')
  // add the new testStep to current testCase
  def newTestStep = tc.insertTestStep( testStepConfig, -1 )
  // set the request which just create with the file content
  def testRequest = newTestStep.getTestRequest()
  testRequest.setRequestContent(file.getText())

  // UPDATED CODE BELOW BASED ON COMMENT

  // you can use in this case HttpRequestConfig (due the type of your
  // testStep you can use this class) to set some additional properties 
  // in your TestStep
  def httpReqCfg = testRequest.getConfig();
  // for example for mediaType as you said in your comment
  httpReqCfg.setMediaType('application/json');

}
```

Note that looks more convenient to use the [`HttpTestRequestStep.clone` method](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/HttpTestRequestStep.html#clone(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase,%20java.lang.String)). However when you invoke this in the groovy, the `testStep` is created but groovy throws the follow exception (I think that here there is something wrong with the SOAPUI API):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.HttpTestRequestStep cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep

However since I think that you're interesting only in use of file content to set 
the request the proposed code above it's enough in your case.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENT:**

You can also use `HttpRequestConfig` to set `mediaType` or to add additional parameters as you require in your comment, take a look at the [`HttpRequestConfig` API](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/config/HttpRequestConfig.html), I also update my code above to show you an example on how to get this object and `setMediaType` take a look on it.

Hope this helps,

Comment: You my friend, are my hero! :D

Comment: @AlexCooke nice to help you `:)`

Comment: Just as a follow up question, is there a way to edit this line to change different values:
def testStepConfig  = testStepFactory.createNewTestStep(tc,newTestStepName,endpoint,'POST')

for instance change the media type or add another custom variable?

edit: just to clarify, I had a look at the API documentation, but it wasn't very clear to me :/

Comment: @AlexCooke I update my answer, take a look on it `:)`, hope this fit your requirements.